# Почему sublime 3 выделяет разделение -- в scss как ошибку?

Tags: scss, sublime-text-3

Установил плагин Scss для саблайм, но при написании класса с двумя дефисами, он подсвечивается крассным. Как исправить?

[image: Скрин с ошибкой]